# Соответствует ли приложение паттерну MVC

Tags: mvc, spring-mvc, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть веб-приложение (Java, Hibernate Spring [MVC, Security, ...], JSP) следующей структуры:

- **entity** (сущности Hibernate)
- **dao** (доступ к БД)
- **service** (бизнес-логика)
- **serviceobjects** (используются в сервисах)
- **controller**
- **bean** (отправляются из контроллера на вьюхи)
- **entitymapper & beanmapper** (~конвертеры)
- **reader & builder** (объекты, выполняющие часть бизнес-логики, используются в сервисах)
- **util** (вспомогательные утилиты)

Удовлетворяет ли такое приложение паттерну MVC?

- Если да, то что здесь является моделью?
- Если нет, то как можно описать такую архитектуру? Подходит ли под какой-либо другой паттерн?

Answer (score 0):

MVC - паттерн Presentation Layer, с его точки зрения Model - это все, кроме View и Controller.

Внутренее строение модели MVC никак не ограничивает. Так что в вашем списке Model - это все, кроме controller.